# After Database Change, I got an error: Additional information: Backend sent unrecognized response type: r

Tags: c#, database, psql

I made some small changes in my database and a working code started to be bugged with an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
> in Npgsql.dll
>
> Additional information: Backend sent unrecognized response type: r

I read some topics about similar errors so I opened a new connection (conn1) and tried like that, but it didnt work. Im kinda lost because I dont know whats causing it. When I tried to debug it, error shows on last line of my code listed down.

My code:

```
private void Pocetna_forma_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_login_info.ReadOnly = true; //stavlja textbox za login da se ne moze editat

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;User Id=postgres;" +
        "Password=123;Database=postgres;");
        conn.Open();
        //query za broj zaposlenika
        NpgsqlCommand broj_zaposlenik = new NpgsqlCommand("Select count(*) from zaposlenici ;", conn);
        count_zaposlenici = Convert.ToInt32(broj_zaposlenik.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();

      

        polje = new int[count_zaposlenici];
        polje_brojac = new int[count_zaposlenici];
        int i = 0;


        //polje za evidenciju dolazaka/odlazaka 
        foreach (var item in polje)
        {
            polje_brojac[i] = 1;
            polje[i] = 1;
            i++;
        }      
    }

    private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var login_form = new Login();
        login_form.FormClosed += (s, ags) => this.Close();
        login_form.Show();
    }

    private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string barcode = txt_barcode.Text;

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;User Id=postgres;" +
        "Password=skalinada123;Database=postgres;");
        conn.Open();

       

        //query provjere za barcode, da li postoji 
        NpgsqlCommand barcode_provjera = new NpgsqlCommand("Select count(*) from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode;", conn);           
        barcode_provjera.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode.ToString());
        Int32 barcode_check = Convert.ToInt32(barcode_provjera.ExecuteScalar());


       

        if (barcode_check > 0)
        {

            //query za dohvacanje zaposlenik_id
            NpgsqlCommand id_zaposlenika = new NpgsqlCommand("Select zaposlenik_id from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode ", conn);
            id_zaposlenika.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode.ToString());
            zaposlenik_id = Convert.ToInt32(id_zaposlenika.ExecuteScalar());//vraca id zaposlenika

            string vrijeme_prijave= DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            string datum = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); ///promjena 

            //query koji provjerava da li je osoba tek dosla na posao ili ce mu se pisati odlazak
            NpgsqlCommand provjera_odlaska = new NpgsqlCommand("select count(*) from radni_sati where datum=@datum and dolazak is not null "+
            " and zaposlenik_id=@zaposlenik_id;", conn);
            provjera_odlaska.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode.ToString());
            provjera_odlaska.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", datum.ToString());
            provjera_odlaska.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zaposlenik_id", zaposlenik_id.ToString());
            count_provjera_odlaska = Convert.ToInt32(provjera_odlaska.ExecuteScalar());
          


            //query za dohvacanje ime i prezime zaposlenika za ispis info-a
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("Select ime,prezime from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode;", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode.ToString());
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
           
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                

                if (polje[zaposlenik_id - 1] == 1 || polje[zaposlenik_id - 1] == 3)
                {
                    info = "Djelatnik " + dr[0].ToString() + " " + dr[1].ToString() + " je uspjesno prijavljen. Vrijeme: " + vrijeme_prijave + "\n";
                    txt_login_info.AppendText(info);//prikazuje tekst djelatnik....
                    
                }
                else if (polje[zaposlenik_id - 1] == 2 || polje[zaposlenik_id - 1] == 4)
                {
                    info = "Djelatnik " + dr[0].ToString() + " " + dr[1].ToString() + " je uspjesno odjavljen. Vrijeme: " + vrijeme_prijave + "\n";
                    txt_login_info.AppendText(info);//prikazuje tekst djelatnik....

                }
                dr.Close();

            }

            if (count_provjera_odlaska == 0)//ako nije upisan radnik na taj dan uopce
            {

                if (polje[zaposlenik_id - 1] == 1)
                {
                    vrijeme_dolaska = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                    vrijemeDolaska = Convert.ToDateTime(vrijeme_dolaska);

                    polje[zaposlenik_id - 1] = 2;
                    // prijavljen_odjavljen = "odjavljen";
                }
                NpgsqlConnection conn1 = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;User Id=postgres;" +
                "Password=123;Database=postgres;");
                conn1.Open();

                //query za upis u tablicu radni_sati
                NpgsqlCommand dolazak = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into radni_sati values(default,@datum," +
                    "(select distinct odjel_id from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "(select odjel from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "(select zaposlenik_id from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "(select ime from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "(select prezime from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "@dolazak,null,null," +
                    "(select bolovanje from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "(select godisnji from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "(select slobodni_dani from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," + "(select slobodni_dani from zaposlenici where barcode=@barcode)," +
                    "null, null,null)", conn1);
                dolazak.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", datum.ToString());
                dolazak.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode.ToString());
                dolazak.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dolazak", vrijemeDolaska.ToString());
                //dolazak.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odlazak", vrijeme_odlaska.ToString());

                NpgsqlDataReader dr1 = dolazak.ExecuteReader();//inserta dolazak
                dr1.Close();
```

So what this does is it scans a barcode of an employee and It saves when he arrives/goes home, how much he worked etc.... Everything works when I scan just one user, but when I try to scan a 2nd one, this error pops up.

If I start my program in debugging mode, and mark that line, 1st time it comes to it, it shows me that error I said, but if I "continue" ones more I get this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in pgsql.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot write to a BufferedStream while the read buffer is not empty if the underlying stream is not seekable. Ensure that the stream underlying this BufferedStream can seek or avoid interleaving read and write operations on this BufferedStream.

Comment: In  my opinion issue is in connection string. You may be passing in an unsupported option there. Double check and cross reference with https://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/.

Comment: Seems like my constraint that I added was wrong, I just edited that, and it works, thanks for trying to help =)

Comment: No issues. What was the constraint exactly ?

Comment: My table called "radni_sati" that this query fills had the foreign key set to a wrong table on a wrong column.... I changed that and It worked. Seems like the Foreign key data was always wrong coz 2 columns comparison always output a wrong values.

Comment: Good you solved it by yourself. Good luck for your project

Comment: Thank you @tousifNoor 
I wont delete this question, maybe it helps someone that runs into the same problem